# Is there a way to tell an html element to ignore any stylesheets?

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to add a drop down to a page that already has a global "select" style.  Is there a way to tell the new select list to ignore the global style?  There's about 1 to 2 zillion existing drop downs that use the global style, so I don't want refactor the existing html.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

there is no easy way to do what you are asking, one approach is to create a CSS class that resets all appropriate attributes for a specific element and its children to make it more complete, here is a good starting point [Element specific CSS reset](http://snipplr.com/view/7438/element-specific-css-reset/)

Comment: This is the best answer.  It was the only answer that addressed the actual question.

Answer (score 46):

Assuming you could set a unique class or id on that element you could use the (<strike>*[limited browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-all)*</strike>) property `all` and set it to `unset` or `initial`

Something like

```
<div class="ignore-css"><div>
```

and

```
.ignore-css{all:unset;}
```

Comment: In 2021, the browser support looks much better already

Answer (score 8):

You can override another style using "!important", like this:

```
a {color: red !important}
```

Or using a more specific selector:

```
*               // a=0 b=0 c=0 -> specificity =   0 
LI              // a=0 b=0 c=1 -> specificity =   1 
UL LI           // a=0 b=0 c=2 -> specificity =   2 
UL OL+LI        // a=0 b=0 c=3 -> specificity =   3 
H1 + *[REL=up]  // a=0 b=1 c=1 -> specificity =  11 
UL OL LI.red    // a=0 b=1 c=3 -> specificity =  13 
LI.red.level    // a=0 b=2 c=1 -> specificity =  21 
#x34y           // a=1 b=0 c=0 -> specificity = 100 
#s12:not(FOO)   // a=1 b=0 c=1 -> specificity = 101
```

See specificity documentation [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity).

---

**UPDATE:**

For example:

You have a global rule:

```
a {color: blue}
```

But you want your links red.
So, you must create the rule below:

```
a {color: red !important}
```

If the global rule also has "!important", you must use a more specific selector:
So, you may use:

```
body a {color: red !important}
```

Comment: I think the select tags have been totally hijacked by a jquery plugin (jqTransform), this surely would have worked otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

you can eaither add cascading styles like:

```
#id1 .class1 select
```

or

```
.class:width:200px !important
```

The !important will make it use the style you want rather than the global one, but if you have to overwrite it it can get a little tricky. You have to use a combination of both.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be most inclined to narrow down your selectors. By that I mean..

```
<div class="newbox">
     <a href="#">I want this to be different.</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.newbox a
{
     color: #888;
     text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Or you could just...

```
<div class="global-css">
<div class="ignore-css">
<div class="important-css">
......
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

where

```
.global-css{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.ignore-css
{
    all:unset;
}
.important-css{
    vertical-align:left !important;
}
```

Comment: And once again, someone has marked it down without adding a comment explaining. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do in this situation is add a unique class to the new element; in this case something like this will work:

```
<select class=i-am-unique>
    <!-- <option> elements in here -->
</select>
```

and then in the stylesheet, find the global rule and add a `:not()` pseudoclass to differentiate:

```
select:not(.i-am-unique) {
    /* global rules */
}

select.i-am-unique {
    /* unique rules */
}
```

This requires minimal code updates, with only 1 class added in your HTML markup, one CSS selector tweaked, and 1 new declaration block for the unique element. Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/CSSBurner/s0daoewu/).

In addition, `:not()` is supported by a [wide swath of browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not), even IE9+ and Safari 3.2+.

Answer (score 0):

actually there is an easy way, what worked perfectly for me was simple CSS rule

```css
display: contents;
```

what this value does is simple causes an element's children to appear as if they were direct children of the element's parent.