# Apply css to all element except one who has specific parent

Tags: html, css

I want to apply CSS to all pages except sidebars. Let me show you an example

```css
.page #buddypress ul.group li
```

I want to apply CSS to all `<li>` tags that are children of `ul.group` class. Problem here is that this class is also exist in sidebar and I don't want to change styling of sidebar. I just want to apply CSS to the page section and not to the sidebar.

I except some kind of `:not(.class)` operation to do that.

Here is what I am trying to do

```css
.page :not(.sidebar) #buddypress ul.group li
```

But this trick doesn't work for me. I really appreciate if someone could solve my problem. I want to apply CSS to all sections except sidebar.

Here is what my HTML looks like:

```
<body>
<div id="buddypress">
<ul class="groups">
<li> </li>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
<ul class="groups">
<li> </li>
</div>
```

Comment: How does your HTML look? It's hard to know what to do, if we don't know the code :-)

Comment: please add your HTML code here. So, we can help you better...

Comment: Note that by using `.page :not(.sidebar) #buddypress li` you are saying `select <li>s that have any element between .page and #buddypress without class .sidebar`. You could replace it with e.g. `.page :not(.sidebar) > #buddypress li`, depending on how your HTML looks. Paste it here and we may be able to help out more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code

```css
div:not(.sidebar) ul.group li {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
// Here i have used div, but you can use whatever tag you have used for sidebar
```

```html
<body class="page">

  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul class="group">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="page-section">
    <ul class="group">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override all css for that element by using its ID (css id overrides css class).
A possibility would be:

```
#id{all:unset}
```

However, this has limited browser support and your specified element should have an ID.
See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36892781/9204431