# How can I apply CSS to any div except those inside a parent div with a specific class?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a global CSS that applies to all div, but I want to make an exception for the [divs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Other_block_elements) inside a parent div with a specific class, which in the example is `should-not-apply` class.

```css
div {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  font-weight: 500 !important;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    0 should apply
  </div>
  <div class="should-not-apply">
    <div>
      <div>
        1.1 should not apply
      </div>
      <div>
        1.2 should not apply
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      2 should not apply
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    3 should apply
  </div>
  <div>
    4 should apply
  </div>
</div>
```

I have looked into [:not Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.php), but it only applies to the elements, not their children.

The reason I need to modify the CSS content this way instead of overwriting, because I am creating the page with [server-side rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting#Server-side_rendering) (SSR) with predefined CSS content, which gets applied before the CSS file here, but I want the CSS content from that SSR instead of this global one.

How can I achieve such task?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply css to all element except one who has specific parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49995946/apply-css-to-all-element-except-one-who-has-specific-parent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work:

```
div:not(.should-not-apply > div) {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    font-weight: 500 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
:not(.should-not-apply div) {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}
div {
  font-size: initial;
  font-weight: initial;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    0 should apply
  </div>
  <div class="should-not-apply">
    <div>
      <div>
        1.1 should not apply
      </div>
      <div>
        1.2 should not apply
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      2 should not apply
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    3 should apply
  </div>
  <div>
    4 should apply
  </div>
</div>
```